# Hive create table and insert table went wrong

Tags: hive, hiveql

I create a table and tend to insert into data from other tables like this:

```
create table novaya.goods_info
( productid      bigint,
  sales_price    bigint,
  supply_price   bigint,
  sale_start_dt  string,
  sale_end_dt    string,
  sold_count     bigint,
  stockquantity  bigint,
  left_count     bigint,
  roletype       string,
  vendorid       string,
  itemid         bigint,
  brand          string,
  ---brandid        bigint,
  categoryid     bigint,
  mngcateid      bigint,
  mng_catecode1  int, mng_cate1   string, 
  mng_catecode2  int, mng_cate2   string, 
  mng_catecode3  int, mng_cate3   string, 
  mng_catecode4  int, mng_cate4   string,   
  mng_catecode5  int, mng_cate5   string     
  --mng_catecode6  int, mng_cate6   string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS textfile
```

but after "insert overwrite table novaya.goods_info", I find that some fields like categoryid has values of null while the values in source table has no null. 
when I change the create way using "STORED AS parquet" or the way using "create table ... as select ...", the problem has not come up. So I wonder what is wrong with my code.
And how to fix it.
Besides, I have already checked the type of the fields both in source tables and target table.

Many thanks.

Comment: This issue comes if there is data type miss match or file format is not correct . is if productid     is not of bigInt type it will null while selected ...

Comment: It sounds like your data may have commas in it.  Since comma is the table delimiter, this would cause your data to be shifted into the wrong columns.  

When you switch to using parquet files, are you also changing the table delimiter?

Comment: there is no momma in the field of categoryid